# how to add values arrays from an arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, string

hi i have two string of arrays. But i can't figure out how to add the some of the value from an array into another.

here is my code.

```
string result[];
string[] hidden;
for (var cek = 1; cek < st.Count(); cek++) 
{
hidden[cek] = result[cek];
}
```

the first string has already filled with values.
and i want to add some values from result into hidden.
but why does it says **use of unassigned local variable**?

is there some mistake or should i use other methods rather than this?

**EDIT 1**
i cannot determine the length of hidden array because it's not always the same, the length is determine by the input words from a textbox that can be count from **st.count()**

Comment: Add string[] hideen=new string[st.count()]

Answer (score 1):

For a start, your variable names are terrible. You use the same variable - cek - inside the for loop and outside. This makes it really hard to see what you mean. What do you want this line to do :

```
string result[cek];
```

Secondly, you haven't given hidden a size so it's unassigned. I presume this is where you are getting the exception.

Thirdly, what do you want hidden to include when the loop is finished? If you can sort this out I think LINQ might definitely help you to work with the arrays.

Comment: yes im sorry i forgot to cut that. second i cant give it a size, or should i use List<string> to make up for it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have two arrays

```
string[] aArray;
string[] bArray;
```

you can use `Union` to merge the two.

```
aArray = aArray.Union(bArray).ToArray();
```

More on `Union` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign your hidden array :

```
string[] hidden = new String[100]; //write length of your array
```

Answer (score 0):

"use of unassigned local variable" because you have not assigned a value to `hidden`.  You must initialize it:

```
int elementCountOfHiddenArray = // something
string[] hidden = new string[elementCountOfHiddenArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error message is that you have only created a reference for the array, not the array itself. Use the `new` keyword to create the array.

There are two more problems with the code:

- Array indexes start at 0, not 1.
- Use the `Length` property of the array. The `Count` method will loop through the array to find out how many items there are, so that's very inefficient.

:

```
// input: string result[]

string[] hidden = new string[result.Length];
for (int cek = 0; cek < result.Length; cek++) {
  hidden[cek] = result[cek];
}
```

You can also use the `CopyTo` method for this:

```
string[] hidden = new string[result.Length];
result.CopyTo(hidden, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well th answer is easy `string[] hidden=new string[st.count()];` and if you want to resize the `hidden` array you should try this `Array.Resize(ref hidden,NewLenght);`.
And you keep getting the error : **use of unassigned local variable** because result is empty.